# Heroku web app deployment error

Tags: python, heroku

I'm getting an Application error when running my python heroku app and the logs show:

at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=python-blackjack.herokuapp.com request_id=38f050c2-bc7e-499a-8112-ee7d4b66bf0c fwd="90.205.68.255" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

does anyone know the issue/s

thanks

Comment: make a `favicon.ico` icon file and add it to the root of your project

Comment: Please do not vandalize your post, people have taken time to answer

Answer (score 0):

This most likely has nothing to do with `favicon.ico`. `H10 App Crashed` means your server could not start, and every request sent to it is erring out.

I recommend to use `heroku restart`, and look in the logs what is causing server to die on startup.

Answer (score -1):

This is a very generic error and question without providing any code. But the most I can see is that you're missing a favicon.ico. Just make one and add it to your project root.

Comment: @ThundaChoc do you hardset the port anywhere in your application?

Comment: @ThundaChoc it's been a couple years since i've used heroku but if i'm not mistaken, this being a console application can't be run from the browser on heroku without being started. Maybe these documentation links will help.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-python                    
https://github.com/heroku/python-getting-started (Check the bottom of the read me)